# How to disable arrow screen navigation in install4j

Tags: java, install4j

we are currently having a bit of a navigation problem in an un/installer in install4j 7.0.6. The un/installer allows to navigate between screen using the arrow keys. This creates some problems, e.g. when the uninstaller welcome screen is shown, pressing the left arrow key causes an exception because there is no screen to go back to.

So the simple solution is to disable the arrow navigation. So my question is, how do you disable the navigation using the arrow keys in install4j?

Edit:
So just to clarify what our current workflow is:

- Installer start
- Installer check if a reg key is present, meaning that an old version is installed (or any version for that matter)
- Uninstaller is started that will ask the user to uninstall first
- Old service is stopped and old files are removed
- Uninstalled finished
- Installer asks where to install the new version
- Files are copied and a service is installed and started
- Installation is finished

There are two problems currently, that may be the most problematic:

- When the Uninstaller is started, going back using the arrow keys eventhough the back button is not shown, causing an exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not go back 1 step in history from com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallWelcomeScreen@1c53fd30
  at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Controller.java:239)
  at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:103)
  at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller.runInProcess(Uninstaller.java:36)
  at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller.main(Uninstaller.java:25)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
  at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
  at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)`
- When the Installer finished the copying of files and creation of the service, the user can go back to the selection of the installation location using the arrow keys, even though the back button is not visible.

Comment: The back button should not be shown for the welcome screen. Please send your .install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com, so we can check the issue.

Comment: The back button is not actually shown, it is just that pressing the arrow key navigates backwards. As an additional note, I added the rough steps that the un/installer does. 

I will also check if I can send you the configuration file and update this question afterwards.

Comment: Okay so it turns out that we repackage the install4j installation in the dependency which is using during the installer build. That dependency claims to contain version 7.0.7 of install4j which was not correct. Instead it contained version 7.0.6, which has the navigation problem. Manually building the installer using the original 7.0.7 version fixed the problem.